# Work done by charged particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, work, coulombs-law

A proton is kept at rest. A positively charged particle is released from rest at a distance d in its field. Consider two experiments; one in which the charged particle is also a proton and in another, a positron. In the same time $t$, the work done on the two moving charged particles is

(a) same as the same force law is involved in the two experiments.

(b) less for the case of a positron, as the positron moves away more rapidly and the force on it weakens.

(c) more for the case of a positron, as the positron moves away a larger distance.

(d) same as the work done by charged particle on the stationary proton

**In the question, it is not mentioned whether same force is being exerted or not, since proton is heavier than positron  shouldn't proton perform greater work than positron ?**

Comment: **In the question, it is not mentioned whether same force is being exerted or not, since proton is heavier than positron shouldn't proton perform greater work than positron ?** Why should the mass matter here?

Answer (score 3):

The force exerted between charged particles is based on Coulomb's Law, which is given by:
$$F=k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$

The force changes based on the distance, $r$ from your proton at rest, so you can integrate from $d$ to $\infty$ with the force equation to get work done.

$\bullet$ It doesn't matter that the positron moves away more rapidly, since the force on it is also decreasing more rapidly.
$\bullet$ The distance it moves also doesn't matter since they'll both cover that distance eventually, and will move on to infinity.
$\bullet$ Same force is exerted, since force between charges does not depend on mass. Gravity depends on mass, and in this case you can safely ignore gravitational attraction because it is negligible for protons.

You're doing this backwards. $F=ma$ is correct. But you're thinking that if $m$ is greater that should affect the force, which is wrong. $F$ is the same, so if $m$ is greater in one case, $a$ will decrease to compensate since $a=\frac{F}{m}$